# Linux: how to check the largest contiguous address range available to a process

Tags: linux, memory-management, mmap, memory-fragmentation

I want to enter the pid at the command line and get back the largest contiguous address space that has not been reserved.  Any ideas?

Our 32 bit app, running on 64 bit RHEL 5.4, craps out after running for a while, say 24 hours.  At that time it is only up to 2.5 gb of memory use, but we get out of memory errors.  We think it failing to mmap large files because the app's memory space is fragmented.  I wanted to go out to the production servers and just test that theory.

Comment: `cat /proc/<pid>/maps` plus some awk/perl/whatever massaging?

Comment: `</proc/self/maps perl -ne'/-/;print hex($``)-$e,$/;$e=hex($'"'"')'| sort -nr|head -n 1`

Comment: Thanks!  Perfect!  I did have to change the double `` to a single ` to get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slighly nicer version of my above comment:

```
#!perl -T

use warnings;
use strict;

scalar(@ARGV) > 0 or die "Use: $0 <pid>";

my $pid = $ARGV[0];
$pid = oct($pid) if $pid=~/^0/;         # support hex and octal PIDs
$pid += 0; $pid = abs(int($pid));       # make sure we have a number

open(my $maps, "<", "/proc/".$pid."/maps") or
        die "can't open maps file for pid ".$pid;

my $max = 0;
my $end = 0;
while (<$maps>) {
        /([0-9a-f]+)-([0-9a-f]+)/;
        $max = hex ($1) - $end if $max < hex ($1) - $end;
        $end = hex ($2);
}

close ($maps);

END {
        print "$max\n";
}
```

Comment: Does `#!perl` actually work? I was under the impression that has always had to be an absolute path.

Comment: @Zack: not really. I put it there just to force `-T` (it just shows I've done too much code-golf).

Comment: Slight nitpick - you forgot to check the space after the end of the last mapping (which finishes at the maximum allowed userspace address, which depends on the configuration of the kernel).

Answer (score 2):

Probably not exactly what you want, but from inside a process it is possible to do binary search by `mmap`ing without allocating. I.e. `mmap(4GB)`, if that fails `mmap(2GB)`, if that succeeds `mmap(3GB`), and so on.

Answer (score 0):

> we get out of memory errors. We think it failing to mmap large files because the app's memory space is fragmented.

However, one can also get OOM errors while still having lots of free virtual address ranges on paper, for example by sufficient lack of RAM+swap. Furthermore your system and/or program(s) may have overcomitting turned off (sysctl -a), or have swapping inhibited (mlock(2)), or you actually have a very blunt limit on mappings (ulimit -v) — the latter is easy to run in given some distributions set such ulimits one way or another.

Comment: We have over 70GB on each server.  We run 24 copies of the app.  It gets up to about 2.5g and then disappears with no core file.  I'm going to make a log entry maybe there is one already, when it fails to malloc or mmap.  Each server uses about 1g of shared mmap memory.

ulimit -v unlimited
overcommit_memory = 0