# How to calculate "Max Contiguous Free Space" that is available in a process?

Tags: linux, memory, x86-64

In My **64 bit linux-rhel62** machine, i would like to calculate the "max contiguous free space" available in a process.
Seems the details may be calculated using /proc/self/maps. But i Do not know how to use that file to calculate the contiguous free space.

Any idea how to do this ?

I have followed the perl script given in [Linux: how to check the largest contiguous address range available to a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403146/linux-how-to-check-the-largest-contiguous-address-range-available-to-a-process?rq=1)

But i am getting output as "18446603339772190720" which is not a acceptable value, (But i understand this is somehow related to 2^64). But the user not accepting this value? is this correct and expected output?
Some old code shows "Physical memory + swap size" as max contiguous free space. But i am not convinced with that too, because i am getting same output every time.

Please let me know, why we are getting such a impossible memory size as free space?
Show me some light, how to find max contiguous free space available?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "max contiguous free space"? A range of the virtual address space that currently has nothing mapped in it? A range of the heap segment that currently is mapped but has nothing allocated in it? The largest possible file you could successfully `mmap()`? The largest `malloc()`/`new()` request that could be satisfied? The largest shared memory or other IPC-type segment that could be created/attached?

Comment: I guess, I am looking for range of the virtual address space that currently has nothing mapped in it. The old code in my library is calculating this max contiguous free space value as (physical memory + swap size), i guess this is wrong. But surely do not know a way to find out this contiguous free space.

[Linux: how to check the largest contiguous address range available to a process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403146/linux-how-to-check-the-largest-contiguous-address-range-available-to-a-process?rq=1)
is giving _18446603340278681600_ ,  this is not correct output i guess. :(

Answer (score 1):

That perl script is looking at

```
/proc/<pid>/maps
```

If you look at the end of a process map on Red Hat you'll see something like this:

```
7fff105a1000-7fff105a2000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

I was able to get that perl script to give a reasonable answer by ignoring that last entry, I modified it to exit the loop when the address is greater than 0x800000000000

```
while (<$maps>) {
        /([0-9a-f]+)-([0-9a-f]+)/;
        last if hex ($1) > hex ( "800000000000" );
        $max = hex ($1) - $end if $max < hex ($1) - $end;
        $end = hex ($2);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have seen that entry, but 'maps' file contains following entries too
`7fdaadedf000-7fdaadf01000 rwxp 003fb000 fd:02 5247220                    /home/build/proj/dev/lib/rhel62/libedgcc45.so
7fff1960f000-7fff19624000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff19666000-7fff19667000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]`

After removal, my final output shows some 141 TB size, Also the prod system shows more of such entries. 141TB is also not possible max contiguous space i guess.

BTW : Can you tell me why you use 800000000000 ?

Comment: User virtual address space is 47 bits, or 128 TB... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246559/how-does-linux-support-more-than-512gb-of-virtual-address-range-in-x86-64